# Git 404 There isn't a GitHub Pages site here

Tags: html, css, git, github, repository

I'm try to host my first page on github, but I got this error message: Git 404 There isn't a GitHub Pages site here. This is my page's URL: Sadap93.github.io. The website name and repository name are same. Repository: https://github.com/Sadap93/Sadap93.github.io.git
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: This might help you setting up your website.
https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/working-with-github-pages

Comment: Check whether you have an error message on "Pages" section of your repo settings. May you have to select a working branch of your repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one possible reason for it-

1. GitHub pages isn't enabled: To solve this, **Repo Settings -> Github Pages section -> Select the main branch**. If it is already there, then wait for some time and refresh your site again.
2. <strike>There is no htaccess file: Create an .htaccess file and type **DirectoryIndex index.html** and save it.</strike> Update: [GitHub Pages doesn’t support .htaccess](https://github.community/t/does-htaccess-work-on-github-pages/137177)

Comment: Hi!
In Github Pages was selected master branch. As you said I changed it to main branch, after that I push my files again and my site is available now. Many thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Sadap Welcome! Also, you can accept my answer so that it will be visible to others who will search for something related to this subject!

Comment: Thanks! the .htaccess file step solved my issue. I  had an existing GitHub pages repo I use for my blog. I renamed the master branch to main branch. But when I went to my site I would get a 404 error. Adding the .htaccess file fixed it.

Comment: Actually, I don't think the .htaccess file did anything in the end. I removed it and my site still shows up.  Maybe the repository needs to be updated before it is displayed? So the act of any push to the repo will fix it?

Comment: @MonicaGranbois Most of the time the issue could be due to the branch (Point 1). But sometimes (I repeat, sometimes! Not always) the site doesn't redirect to the index.html by itself and shows a 404, and that is when we are required to perform Point 2.

Comment: @MonicaGranbois Also, I think once we get the site working, it's safe to remove the .htaccess file, because I just deleted it from one of my live repos and everything feels just fine. It's Strange because initially, I was having a problem with the same repo. The index.html was up at username.github.io/index.html and I was getting a 404 at username.github.io. Adding a .htaccess file had solved that problem.

Comment: @Nil It looks like GitHub doesn’t support .htaccess files. See https://github.community/t/does-htaccess-work-on-github-pages/137177. In my case I renamed the default branch, so I’m guessing, the site needed to be rebuilt on GitHub’s side in order to see the new name. And so the push did that. OR the push was a coincidence and something was cached, and I just needed to wait for the the cache to reset.

Comment: @MonicaGranbois Yeah, if the branch is properly selected, I think all we can do is wait for some time. I've Updated the answer! Thanks for communicating your observation!

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you select it from GitHub Page?
2. Can you show me your GitHub Pages settings?

Open your Repo then go to setting tab and scroll to down.
(Repo settings -> Github Pages)

If not then configure it by choosing your particular repo. And try to give name your repo by your own name. (Better approach)

[image]